# Will the two capacitors be charged in this circuit?

Tags: homework-and-exercises, electric-circuits, electrical-resistance, capacitance, batteries

Is such a circuit possible to exist with the two capacitors charging?

Because if we considered the outer loop using Kirchhoff's law we get:

ℰ = q1/C1 + q2/C2

But since the two capacitors are initially uncharged, the two terms of the equation increase, that is, q1 and q2 increase, while they equal ℰ which is a constant.
How's that possible? and will the capacitors be charged? also how could we calculate the time constant for it?

[image: A circuit with two capacitors and two resistors.]

Comment: comment deleted.  changed my mind

Comment: Of course such a circuit can exist. You could build it right now if you had the parts. Analyzing it is somewhat more complex than just one R and one C, but not wildly more complex.

Comment: Yes, I can build it but the current might go in the resistors rather than charging the capacitors. I'm just asking about the capacitors, will they be charged in this case?

Comment: The current will run trough the resistors AND the capacitors. You simply have to apply Kirchhoff and believe what his formulas tell you. The man is correct, you know, energy and charge conservation are backing him up pretty nicely.

Comment: Yes, of course they will charge - in steady state R1 and R2 will act as a voltage divider, so C1 and C2 must charge up to have those same voltages across them. The tricky part is during the charging, when the voltage divider is not what you think it is because of the charging current to C2.

Comment: @JonCuster: Technically the OP has a point that the circuit is not well defined in the sense that one has to add an internal resistance to the battery, otherwise the capacitor charging currents will diverge. I just realized that...

Comment: @JonCuster No, that circuit is not well drawn - it neglects the resistance of the wires that hook up the source to the rest of the circuit, and at zero charge on the capacitors that's an inconsistent approximation.

Comment: @CuriousOne - but that problem exists in the circuit without the resistors as well, even after reducing the series capacitors to one equivalent capacitor. Yet, the steady state result is straightforward in that case, and this one as well. It is kind of like assuming op-amps have infinite input impedance and infinite gain, and then complaining that leads to weird circuit behavior - the problem has been slightly oversimplified.

Comment: @EmilioPisanty - of course, and any good electrical engineer would realize that immediately and include the source impedance. As a literal 'physics' problem it has issues, as a EE problem it is just fine. Different backgrounds, different issues...

Comment: @JonCuster: The fact remains that with a perfect battery, the circuit currents diverge, which is not a well defined behavior. That we still have to understand what is happening at the internal node is different matter.

Comment: @CuriousOne: but how could a constant equal two increasing variables? That's what the man said, and I trust him, that no current will go in the capacitors.

Comment: I have no idea what you mean by that. What constant? There are two charge variables in this problem, one for each capacitor, then there are three voltage nodes and like 10 currents. Kirchhoff tells you how to derive the equations from that and then you have to solve them. What will happen is that when the battery circuit is closed, an infinite current will flow to charge the capacitors and then there will still be an exponential current flow from the resistors to the center node of the capacitors. That's unphysical, so you would have to limit the current in the battery.

Answer (score 5):

As drawn, the circuit, assuming ideal circuit elements, is problematic for the reason you've deduced (KVL gives a contradiction).  One interpretation is that there is infinite large current for an infinitesimal time which instantaneously charges the capacitors to their final steady state voltages.

To gain some insight, add a resistance $r$ in series with the battery; this models the internal resistance of a physical battery.  You will find that the initial battery current is equal to $\mathcal{E}/r$ and that it decays to a steady state value of $\mathcal{E}/(R_1 + R_2 + r)$.

Thus, see that as $r \rightarrow 0$, the initial current goes to infinity but this is clearly unphysical, no physical voltage source can supply arbitrarily large current.

In fact, there are other mechanisms such as the inescapable inductance of the loop and radiation resistance that must be included in the model in the case that $r$ is 'small enough'.

In summary, it is possible (and well known in the EE community) that one can draw circuit diagrams that, assuming ideal circuit elements, lead to contradictions, e.g., two different parallel connected voltage sources.  The key is to understand that, in order to model physical circuits, one must often insert additional ideal circuit elements such as, in this case, a resistor in series with the battery to model the finite short circuit current capability.

Answer (score 3):

No, that circuit cannot exist in that regime. You are neglecting the internal resistance of the wires between the voltage source and the capacitors, and if the capacitors are discharged (in which case the voltage over them is zero) that's no longer a good approximation. You therefore need to insert a small resistance on either side of the voltage source, which will then govern the $RC$ charging time of the capacitors.

Comment: So what would happen if we actually build the circuit? No current will go through the capacitors or what?

Comment: It will just take some (small) time to charge, since the wires' resistance can be small but not zero (superconductors aside, in which case how sure are you that your source has no internal resistance?).

Comment: If we neglect the resistances, the next leading term that one would see in a real implementation are the inductances of the wire loop, which would make this into an RLC parallel circuit that would show damped oscillations. This would happen even with superconductors, since one can not reduce inductance to zero.

Comment: @EmilioPisanty I tried to build my source using only superconductors, and discovered I *still* had source impedance in the *inductance* of the circuit!